# Need to replace specific line (1st line in the text) in with open & for loop

Tags: python

I have an issue with a text file where I need to replace the 1st line from (Name 80010695) to (Name 80010695_05_76) noting I do the for loop as the (05_76) is changeable across the files.

When I use the append the write is removing all the txt then adding the needed txt.

What is needed is a syntax to write a specific line without removing any other.

```py
with open("D:/Upper - Sources/Antenna/OneDrive_1_11-21-2019/80010965/pattern/source.txt",'r')as source:

source_=source.readlines() #creating the source list of the antennas file names

for i in range(0,int(len(source_))):

   source_[i]=source_[i].replace("\n","")

     for L in source_: #creating the for loop to check all the names of the files that need edit

         with open("D:/Upper - Sources/Antenna/OneDrive_1_11-21-2019/80010965/pattern/" + L,'a')as msi:

            msi.writelines("Name " + L)

            with open("D:/Upper - Sources/Antenna/OneDrive_1_11-21-2019/80010965/pattern/index.txt",'w')as index:

                index.write(L+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
with open ('index.txt', 'r') as f:
  old_data = f.read()

new_data = old_data.replace('what_change', 'for_what_change')

with open ('index.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(new_data)
```

Comment: I think it will remove all occurences of `what_change`